# Captured image became blurry after cropping it in android

Tags: android

When capture an image from camera ,it looks clear as captured but after cropping image, its quality decreases and it looks blurry.Here is my code to crop an image .Please help me to solve this issue.

```
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);// 256
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);

        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 6);
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/biokys/cropimage instead.

Comment: Thanks rom4ek for your feedback.